# Symfony - Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class App\Entity\Question could not be converted to string

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am learning Symfony and I ran into this problem.

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class App\Entity\Question could not be converted to string

My goal is to add via the form to the database.

I think I am using my EntityType wrong, here is my form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('question', EntityType::class,
                    [
                        'class' => Question::class
                    ]
                )
                ->add(
                    'answer',
                    TextType::class
                )
                ->add(
                    'valid',
                    ChoiceType::class,
                    [
                        'choices' => [
                            'true' => 1,
                            'false' => 0
                        ]
                    ]
                )
                ->add(
                    'save',
                    SubmitType::class
                )
            ;
        }
```

And here is my Controller where I build my form:

```
 $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$answer = new Answer();

        $form = $this->createForm(ExamDatabaseInteractionType::class, $answer);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            $entityManager->persist($answer);
            $entityManager->flush();

        }


        return [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ];
```

I am guessing the database structure is also important here:

```
describe question;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| question | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

describe answer;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| question_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| answer      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| valid       | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I hope I structured my question well, this is my first question on stack overflow.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The problem lies in your form definition. When using an element of type `Entity`, you need to provided a property that should be used when rendering the element. One exception to this would be to implement a method called `__toString()`, but I do not recommend it. Try adding `'choice_label' => 'question'` to your EntityType definition. You can read more about all of the available options for this form element in the official documentation.

Comment: I did try to add the ```__toString()``` function but i doesn't really work. If however i set ```data_class``` to null . I get the following error  ```Cannot read index "question" from object of type "App\Entity\Answer" because it doesn't implement \ArrayAccess.```

Comment: `EntityType` by default is for *selecting* an entity from the database, not for adding one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admire how Symfony has everything very well documented, and your case is not an exception. See the docs for [Entity Type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

It has a field option [`choice_label`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label):

> This is the property that should be used for displaying the entities as text in the HTML element.
>
> If left blank, the entity object will be cast to a string and so must have a `__toString()` method. You can also pass a callback function for more control.

So, you do not specify `choice_label`, and you do not have `__toString` implemented, hence the error.

What you should do:

```
$builder
    ->add('question', EntityType::class,
    [
        'class' => Question::class,
        'choice_label' => 'questionName',
    ])
```

OR implement [`__toString()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) in `Entity\Question`.

Comment: @learningsymfony just to emphasize: the object (read the entity) must have the `__toString()` method implemented, not the form or whatever. so in your case: the Question entity.

Comment: If i set ```'data_class' => Answer::class,``` `  and set(in my question entitiy) ```public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->question;
    }``` My form just shows me all the data in the database. What i want to do is add new fields to the database.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your question. You had trouble with accessing an object as a string. I gave you an answer to solve it. Now you're saying something else is wrong. If your new problem is not connected to the access object as string problem (and I feel it doesn't, it seems like just another problem in line), you should open a new question.